# Necesito integrar Firebase a mi app de forma modular

Tags: firebase, ios, swift

Estoy desarrollando un app en la cual quiero trabajar de forma modular: creando diferentes frameworks cada uno con las diferentes funcionalidades de la app. Para esto, quiero usar Firebase tanto para la parte de autenticación como también Firestore. Mi duda es, que al generar un proyecto en Firebase, lo creo con el bundle id del proyecto general, pero no se como tendría que hacer para que pueda usar Firebase en cada framework por separado y poder hacer las pruebas correspondientes a la app a medida que voy desarrollando.
Para integrar mis propios frameworks a la app, los cargo con cocoapods desde el repositorio en github de cada uno.

Comment: Si no agregas algo de código probablemente termine tu pregunta cerrada porque parece estar basada en opiniones y no es muy claro lo que quieras hacer. Te recomiendo que leas cómo realizar una buena pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es usar firebase con Functions para hacer trabajos a base de rutas y no de el package de Firebase en android, de esta manera Firebase funciona como un REST API.

Por otro lado hacer una app modular es una cosa distinta y hacer diferentes apps por modulos es otra. Puesto que en una solo rehusar codigo y en otra infraestructurra.

**Documentacion**
[**Forma de usarlo Firebase Cloud Functions**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?hl=es-419)
[**Integracion con Real Time**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?hl=es-419)

**Consejo**
Debes definir bien que quieres y si lo que necesitas es separar la app y rehusar el codigo y funcionalidad de firebase pues usa Cloud Functions ( de firebase ) para que desde cualquier app con cualquier **`applicationId`** pueda hacer CRUD y todo desde una misma base de datos o varias.